# How to prove the fraction identity without using calculator

Tags: inequality, fractions

How to prove without calculator that

$$ \frac{1}{1001} + \frac{1}{3001}  > \frac{1}{1000}$$

Comment: Think about what the sum of the fractions produces (_don't_ multiply out the denominator!).  How might you make a comparison of that sum to 1/1000?

Comment: Multiply everything by $1001 \cdot 3001$

Answer (score 27):

$$\frac{1}{1001}+\frac{1}{3001}=\frac{3}{3003}+\frac{1}{3001}>\frac{3}{3003}+\frac{1}{3003}=\frac{4}{3003}>\frac{4}{4000}=\frac{1}{1000}$$

Answer (score 7):

HINT:

$$\frac1{1000}-\frac1{1001}=\frac{1001-1000}{1000\cdot1001}=\frac1{1000\cdot1001}<\frac1{3001}$$